# memory leaks originating when pushing back in Navigation Application

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

What can be the reason of memory leaks that originating when I push back to previous view (Navigation Based Application)?

[image]

Edited: code added

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setTableView:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
[self setSearchController:nil];
[self setSearchBar:nil];
toolBar=nil;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
[tableView release];
[searchBar release];
[_toolBar release];
[nominalsArr release];
[searchController release];
[filteredItems release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Another edit

[image]

Comment: When you push back the last controller is released and probably dealloced, you must be forgetting a release... Can you post the controller code?

Comment: @ fbernardo Hello, thank you much for yesterday's help. Please, see edit.

Comment: No problem, what about the code related to the image?

Comment: @fbernardo nominalsArr is capsula in which I store data retrieved from DB. It's retained and I release it in dealloc meth.  self.nominalsArr=[dbAccsess returnNominals:subCountryID];

Comment: Use data in custom cell class in drawRect method: NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:theNominal.nominalImg ofType:@"png"];

Comment: Hmm, instruments shows you 3bytes, that's very small, like a char* or something... I would start by replacing or commenting out all the "outside" of the controller class calls and testing if it still hapens.

Comment: "  I would start by replacing or commenting out all the "outside" of the controller class calls and testing if it still hapens ". What do you mean?

Comment: By the way... I'm calling DB method in ViewWillAppear of controller

Comment: For example, if you have anything that is created outside the class, a object, a char*, anything. Try to isolate the problem, something like "hey, if i don't call strdup here it won't leak...".

Comment: Wait, show me the sqlNominals property declaration and your returnNominals method.

Comment: There's strange that leak happens Only when I hit back...

Comment: That's because the navigation controller is deallocing your controller.

Comment: When a release s called retain count goes dow not up, so -1

Comment: In my case looks like +1. See another edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your last image what's happening is:

- you are allocing and then autoreleasing a NSString
- then you are assigning it to a retain property, that guess what, retains it (retain count +1)
- then you are not releasing it and appparently can't access it anymore (leaked)

Comment: Well, the strings are not leaking anymore, there's another problem at moment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544846/ios-memory-leak-in-simple-mvc-model . Anyway, meanwhile you helped me. thanks.